# Ler ficheiros JList e apresentar conteúdo numa JTextArea

Tags: java

```
JTextArea caixaTexto = new JTextArea();

 try {
    String[] arrayLinhas = null;        
    int i = 0;                          

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(diretoriaExecucao + "/" + valorSelecionado));

    while(br.ready()){
        String linha = br.readLine();
        arrayLinhas[i] = linha;
        i++;
    }
    caixaTexto.setText(arrayLinhas.toString());  //imprimo caixa texto
    br.close();                         

} catch (IOException e2) {
    e2.printStackTrace();
}
```

Tenho uma lista da qual seleciono um ficheiro, leio esse ficheiro e imprimo o output na JTextArea caixa de texto.

Dá me um erro de null exception na linha:

arrayLinhas[i] = linha;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adaptei o seu código pra ele funcionar. Você não precisa de um array se o único objetivo é mostrar o conteúdo numa área de texto.

```
try {
    caixaTexto.setText(""); // Limpar o TextArea
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(diretoriaExecucao + "/" + valorSelecionado));

    while(br.ready()){
        String texto = br.readLine() + "\n"; 
        caixaTexto.append(texto); 
    }
    
    br.close();                         
} catch (IOException e2) {
    e2.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

#### Versão antiga

Você não instanciou o array, veja esta linha

```
String[] arrayLinhas = null;
```

Deveria ser

```
String[] arrayLinhas = new String[tamanhoDoArray];
```

Se você não souber a quantidade de linhas de antemão, pode substituir o array por um `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList<String> listaLinhas = new ArrayList<String>();

//...
while(br.ready()){
    String linha = br.readLine();
    listaLinhas.add(linha);
}
```

Comment: Sim mas agora tenho o problema de quando escrevo na caixa de texto com a 1ª solução não me aparece o texto mas sim codificado.

Comment: Isso é outro problema, jovem. Você pode abrir outra pergunta com isso.

Comment: pode ser só List em vez de array List?

Comment: Do lado esquerdo (declaração) sim, do lado direito (instanciação) não.

Comment: No caso do append não da, isto porque sempre que carregar noutros ficheiros aparece sempre o texto que já lá está.

Comment: Limpa ele antes, ora. Editei a resposta

Comment: e como mudo de linha? /n não funciona

Comment: e vota no meu post pff para te marcar responda correta

Comment: É \n mesmo, cara.

Answer (score 1):

O NullPointerException ocorre pois `arrayLinhas` não está inicializado.

Minha sujestão é substituir ele por uma `List`, como o `ArrayList` e usar o método add para as linhas. Depois você pode pegar um array de linhas se precisar com um `list.toArray()`

Outra solução para seu caso é usar o append do JTextArea diretamente:

```
JTextArea caixaTexto = new JTextArea();

try {
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(diretoriaExecucao, valorSelecionado));

     while(br.ready()){
         String linha = br.readLine();
         caixaTexto.append(linha);//imprime continuamente na caixa texto
     }
 br.close();                         

 } catch (IOException e2) {
     e2.printStackTrace();
 }
```